# Enable Rich Text in a Site Workflow Initiation Form for a Multiple Line Column w/o InfoPath?

Tags: workflow, infopath, site-column, rich-text, initiation-form

I've created a site workflow that users manually start and that collects data through an initiation form, which then passes the data to a Word document in a library. The initiation form uses site columns I've created this purpose. For those columns set up as a multiple lines of text data type, I'd like the user to be able to input enhanced rich text like HTML, pictures, tables, etc into the initiation form itself.

I've already specified the type of text the site column will allow to Enhanced rich text and have had no luck.

Is there a way to enable/edit this through SharePoint Designer only? Or do I have to set the properties of the control on the initiation form through InfoPath?

I'm using an OnPremise SharePoint 2013 environment for this workflow.

Comment: My solution was to scrap the out of the box SharePoint initiation form for the Word document and to use InfoPath as the basis for the web form.

Comment: Tony, Did you ever figure out a solution for this problem? Thanks, Tim